# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure with secured Rest webservice

Tags: java, rest, ssl, keystore

I am trying to consume secured rest api in java, having abc.crt, aaa.pem and xyz.key certificates provided by client.

Imported aaa.pem into jdk default truststore 'cacerts' and created keystore.jks using abc.crt and xyz.key and same refered in code like below:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/keystore.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
            System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

But getting below exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

To resolve this downloaded certificate from browser and imported but this time end up with below

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1769)
```

anything wrong, Please correct me.
SSL Debug:

```
<CN=xxxx, O=xxxxx, C=xx>
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1.2
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 269
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 03 61 6B A3 89 9B A5   35 44 DF 9A 19 4D C1 F3  ..ak....5D...M..
0010: 4D 7B 56 15 92 C7 7A BB   E3 D3 70 48 D7 BB 5F FF  M.V...z...pH.._.
0020: 8D 4A 83 F3 D3 46 F7 9C   82 35 C9 99 EC E7 42 66  .J...F...5....Bf
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 5A 02 99 9D C4 BC 72 E1   34 A8 46 18 7E 93 DA E7  Z.....r.4.F.....
0010: 67 E5 5A 2B 07 21 1C A0   CC 6F 5D 7E 47 75 89 7A  g.Z+.!...o].Gu.z
Server Nonce:
0000: 1C B1 ED 05 9C 11 5C 5F   BE 0C 28 67 0A B1 D0 04  ......\_..(g....
0010: 56 42 11 86 52 4A 95 8D   F9 69 3C 2A 9A 2F 69 02  VB..RJ...i<*./i.
Master Secret:
0000: FD 12 39 65 72 0C 0B 59   F3 60 BD 7F DE 5D 8C EC  ..9er..Y.`...]..
0010: D1 DE 3E 37 DA E3 35 B5   B6 1C E4 57 D7 18 5E 35  ..>7..5....W..^5
0020: F8 E0 24 2F 2C DB 68 89   99 25 8F D0 97 17 B8 70  ..$/,.h..%.....p
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: 77 4E C7 9D F1 A1 34 2D   89 AC FD 3B 6B EB 72 51  wN....4-...;k.rQ
Server write key:
0000: C0 02 D9 65 D9 EC 8C 8E   4F 5C B3 8A E7 21 C8 32  ...e....O\...!.2
Client write IV:
0000: 7C E6 07 AB                                        ....
Server write IV:
0000: C6 8C 5E EE                                        ..^.
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 177, 250, 131, 167, 57, 62, 209, 48, 184, 202, 65, 25 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, called closeSocket()
main, Exception while waiting for close javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Cipher ignored:

```
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
```

**UPDATE:**
same thing working with python script:

```
def somefunction(data, headers):
  response = requests.post("https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx", data=data, headers=headers, verify='/path/to/root/ca/aaa.pem', cert=('/path/to/crt/abc.crt','/path/to/key/xyz.key'), stream=True)
  headres = {'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
  data = '<xyz>something</xyz>'
```

Comment: I faced similar error multiple times and it's due to different reasons. What I did is to enable ssl debug and check the logs, most of the time it's giving me good insights. Please refer to below link on how to do debugging with SSL. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: @Siddu Did you add all the certificates to form the right `chain of trust`? Did you miss trusting any Sub CA's certificates?

Comment: @ always_a_rookie_to_learn, Yes added all the certificates to form right trust. Don't have any sub CA's.

Comment: _Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication_ Your server is requesting for a client certificate and your client is unable to find a suitable one. 1) Did you set the client certificate CAs in server side? 2) does keystore.jks contains the client certificate and is it in the correct path?

Comment: @pedrofb, I am new to SSL, Can u help me in setting the client certificate CAs in server side? Yes keystore.jks has client certificate and its in correct path

Comment: It depends on the specific server that you are using to deal with SSL: apache, tomcat, IIS, etc. Basically you need to configure a keystore containing the root certificate of the accepted Certificate Authorities

Comment: will give background of the issue: I want to consume secured rest streaming api in WSO2 EI for some reasons direct option is not available in WSO2 EI. So same thing can do in Java and build a jar and deploy the same. In my wso2 ei configuration i can call qualified class name then will play with response in WSO2 EI level. In WSO2 EI has keystore&truststore configured all certificates as well.